# Request Entity Too Large Error 413 : Contact Form 7 attachment sending to email

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, contact-form-7

Hello I am still stuck on Request Entity Too Large Error 413 on localhost and intranet server. I have tried to increase size of file upload and max post size in many ways.
I have added below on .htaccess file

```
    php_value upload_max_filesize 100M
php_value post_max_size 128M
php_value memory_limit 256M
```

added below on theme function.php

```
@ini_set( 'upload_max_size' , '100M' );
@ini_set( 'post_max_size', '100M');
@ini_set( 'max_execution_time', '300' );
```

I have added below on upload htaccess file:

```
<Directory "/wp-content/uploads">
    LimitRequestBody 20971520
</Directory>
```

It doen't work and I still get this error:

```
Mailer: Gmail
Request Entity Too Large
Request Entity Too Large
Error 413
```

Comment: Yeah , finally I changed the mail setting to hotmail.com . Now I can send large file. Thanks a lot .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I used office365 and gmail, I can send only less than 6 MB. Finally I changed SMTP mail setting to hotmail.com. The attachment file is sent out to mail.